# GStreamer opencv videowriter fails to create pipeline

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, gstreamer

I'm working with Opencv 4.4 and using GStreamer 1.18 running in Windows c++. I have added the gstreamer to the opencv compilation.

I'm trying to run a program that displays in a browser what is displayed in a webcam using gstreamer, but when I'm initializing the VideoWriter it's always failing on creating the pipeline.

When I run the gst-launch it works fine, and I can see it in a browser.

```
gst-launch-1.0 ksvideosrc device-index=0 ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,width=320,height=240 ! clockoverlay shaded-background=true font-desc="Sans 38" ! theoraenc ! oggmux ! tcpserversink host=127.0.0.1 port=5200
```

When I'm running in my program

```
VideoWriter writer;
VideoCapture cap_;
cap_.open(0);


if (!writer.isOpened())
{
    writer.open(
        " appsrc ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,width=320,height=240 ! clockoverlay shaded-background=true font-desc=\"Sans 38\" ! theoraenc ! oggmux ! tcpserversink host=127.0.0.1 port=5200 ",
        CAP_GSTREAMER,
        10,
        Size(320, 240),
        true);
if (!writer.isOpened())
    {
        Log(INFO) << getBuildInformation();
    }
}
```

it fails when creating the pipeline

```
[ WARN:0] global C:\opencv\opencv44\opencv-4.4.0\modules\videoio\src\cap_gstreamer.cpp (480) cv::GStreamerCapture::isPipelinePlaying OpenCV | GStreamer warning: GStreamer: pipeline have not been created
[ WARN:0] global C:\opencv\opencv44\opencv-4.4.0\modules\videoio\src\cap_gstreamer.cpp (1274) cv::CvVideoWriter_GStreamer::close_ OpenCV | GStreamer warning: No source in GStreamer pipeline. Ignore
[ERROR:0] global C:\opencv\opencv44\opencv-4.4.0\modules\videoio\src\cap.cpp (563) cv::VideoWriter::open VIDEOIO(GSTREAMER): raised OpenCV exception:

OpenCV(4.4.0) C:\opencv\opencv44\opencv-4.4.0\modules\videoio\src\cap_gstreamer.cpp:144: error: (-215:Assertion failed) ptr in function 'cv::`anonymous-namespace'::GSafePtr<struct _GstElement>::get'
```

My html works fine when using the gst-launch

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <head>
                <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
                <title>gst-stream</title>
        </head>
        <body>
                <video width="640" height="480" autoplay="">
                        <source src="http://localhost:5200">
                </video>
        </body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know why this error is happening or how can I handle to find a solution?

the general information displayed

```
General configuration for OpenCV 4.4.0 =====================================
  Version control:               unknown

  Extra modules:
    Location (extra):            C:/opencv/opencv44/opencv_contrib-4.4.0/modules
    Version control (extra):     unknown

  Platform:
    Timestamp:                   2020-11-30T15:46:07Z
    Host:                        Windows 10.0.19042 AMD64
    CMake:                       3.16.5
    CMake generator:             Visual Studio 16 2019
    CMake build tool:            C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/MSBuild/Current/Bin/MSBuild.exe
    MSVC:                        1924

  CPU/HW features:
    Baseline:                    SSE SSE2 SSE3
      requested:                 SSE3
    Dispatched code generation:  SSE4_1 SSE4_2 FP16 AVX AVX2 AVX512_SKX
      requested:                 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX FP16 AVX2 AVX512_SKX
      SSE4_1 (17 files):         + SSSE3 SSE4_1
      SSE4_2 (2 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2
      FP16 (1 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
      AVX (5 files):             + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX
      AVX2 (31 files):           + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2
      AVX512_SKX (7 files):      + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2 AVX_512F AVX512_COMMON AVX512_SKX

  C/C++:
    Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
    C++ standard:                11
    C++ Compiler:                C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.24.28314/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe  (ver 19.24.28316.0)
    C++ flags (Release):         /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise     /EHa /wd4127 /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4512 /wd4589 /MP  /MD /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG
    C++ flags (Debug):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise     /EHa /wd4127 /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4512 /wd4589 /MP  /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1
    C Compiler:                  C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.24.28314/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
    C flags (Release):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise     /MP   /MD /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG
    C flags (Debug):             /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise     /MP /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1
    Linker flags (Release):      /machine:x64  /INCREMENTAL:NO
    Linker flags (Debug):        /machine:x64  /debug /INCREMENTAL
    ccache:                      NO
    Precompiled headers:         NO
    Extra dependencies:
    3rdparty dependencies:

  OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 aruco bgsegm bioinspired calib3d ccalib core datasets dnn dnn_objdetect dnn_superres dpm face features2d flann fuzzy gapi hfs highgui img_hash imgcodecs imgproc intensity_transform line_descriptor ml objdetect optflow phase_unwrapping photo plot quality rapid reg rgbd saliency shape stereo stitching structured_light superres surface_matching text tracking ts video videoio videostab world xfeatures2d ximgproc xobjdetect xphoto
    Disabled:                    -
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 alphamat cnn_3dobj cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev cvv freetype hdf java js julia matlab ovis python2 python3 sfm viz
    Applications:                tests perf_tests apps
    Documentation:               NO
    Non-free algorithms:         NO

  Windows RT support:            NO

  GUI:
    Win32 UI:                    YES
    VTK support:                 NO

  Media I/O:
    ZLib:                        build (ver 1.2.11)
    JPEG:                        build-libjpeg-turbo (ver 2.0.5-62)
    WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020f)
    PNG:                         build (ver 1.6.37)
    TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.0.10)
    JPEG 2000:                   build Jasper (ver 1.900.1)
    OpenEXR:                     build (ver 2.3.0)
    HDR:                         YES
    SUNRASTER:                   YES
    PXM:                         YES
    PFM:                         YES

  Video I/O:
    DC1394:                      NO
    FFMPEG:                      YES (prebuilt binaries)
      avcodec:                   YES (58.54.100)
      avformat:                  YES (58.29.100)
      avutil:                    YES (56.31.100)
      swscale:                   YES (5.5.100)
      avresample:                YES (4.0.0)
    GStreamer:                   YES (1.18.1)
    DirectShow:                  YES
    Media Foundation:            YES
      DXVA:                      YES

  Parallel framework:            Concurrency

  Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)

  Other third-party libraries:
    Intel IPP:                   2020.0.0 Gold [2020.0.0]
           at:                   C:/opencv/opencv44/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/icv
    Intel IPP IW:                sources (2020.0.0)
              at:                C:/opencv/opencv44/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/iw
    Lapack:                      NO
    Eigen:                       NO
    Custom HAL:                  NO
    Protobuf:                    build (3.5.1)

  OpenCL:                        YES (NVD3D11)
    Include path:                C:/opencv/opencv44/opencv-4.4.0/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
    Link libraries:              Dynamic load

  Python (for build):            C:/Users/maor/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe

  Java:
    ant:                         NO
    JNI:                         NO
    Java wrappers:               NO
    Java tests:                  NO

  Install to:                    C:/opencv/opencv44/build/install
```

Answer (score 0):

Like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61394756/how-to-use-opencv-videowriter-with-gstreamer), I believe that this is a bug in OpenCV, which should be fixed by [this PR](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/20796/files), or maybe [this one](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/20801) (or maybe both).

Indeed, it seems like the OpenCV code used to work with some version of GStreamer that would set the error pointer to `NULL` when the function succeeds, but that is not guaranteed with 1.16.2 in my experience (and from the documentation).

With those PRs, it should properly use the return value instead of relying on the state of the error pointer.

Comment: I'm using OpenCV 4.8 and GStreamer 1.22.5 on Windows. When my executable file dynamically links the dll of gstreamer from its original location(C:\gstreamer\1.0\msvc_x86_64\bin), there is no problem. But moving all the dlls to the same location in where my executable(for distribution), the problem occurs.